# How to fix Mocha global symbols for TypeScript in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, mocha.js

After installing Mocha typings from `@types/mocha` and configuring TypeScript compiler:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "newLine": "lf",
    "outDir": "target",
    "types": ["node", "mocha"],
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "target",
    "actors/test",
    "actors/typings"
  ]
}
```

I still get unresolved global symbol warnings/suggestions in IntelliJ IDEA visual editor for TypeScript Mocha tests:

[image: screenshot]

How do I fix that? The tests run successfully, but I get this annoying popup all the time when editing the test source code.

Comment: can't recreate using same config. From the screenshot it seems that `it` is resolved, but the IDE suggests to import it as if it's a module that has to be imported. Please `Ctrl+click` on `it` - what declaration are you taken to?

Comment: @lena, I'm taken to global `it` in `node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts`.

Comment: for me, it jumps to the corresponding method in `Mocha.TestFunction` interface in `node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts` - is it the same for you? I'm using the latest typings version - 5.2.5

Comment: @lena, Yup, the problem fixed after upgrading typings from `5.2.2` to `5.2.5`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem fixed after upgrading Mocha typings from `5.2.2` to `5.2.5` (thanks to @lena).